# Need to compare a pipe delimited field to a string in Presto via SQL

Tags: sql

Sample data

```
yourfoo= foo|bar|foo
recofoo= bar
```

I need to compare in a case statement when the value of the field recofoo matches any of the strings between the pipes of the field yourfoo then “Y” else “N”

I’ve tried a bunch of regex with no luck. I’m using presto/hive to write my SQL if that matters

Thanks!

Comment: `sql` is not enough here. Specify the server and what you tried by now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need regex here, `LIKE` will do:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE '|' || yourfoo || '|' LIKE '%|' || recofoo || '|%';
```

For the sample data you gave, the query would become:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE '|foo|bar|foo|' LIKE '%|bar|%';
```

You can see that this would match for the sample data.

Comment: thank you tim! I also found out how to do this in a case statement to compare strings in a field: CASE WHEN foo_field LIKE (concat('%',bar_field,'%'))
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as foo_bar_match,

Answer (score 0):

syntax may be a little different depending the database you are using but for HIVE/PRESTO. FYI- parentheses are important here inside/out.

CASE WHEN field_1 LIKE (concat('%',field2,'%'))
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as field_1_match